store all of my inputs in local storage in a list with an option to delete them
`
basically i want to put all my inputs from my html form into a list on a separate website using local storage this website being my "admin" site which only i can see. I want to make it so all the form submissions are stored and shown/displayed on this site with an option to delete all them
submission site
    <fieldset style="width: fit-content; margin: 0 auto; font-size: 30px;">
        <form action="index.html">
        <legend>Submit ID</legend>
        <label>ID<br />
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/></label><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="getData()">
    </form>
    </fieldset>

function getData(){ var email = document.getElementById("email").value; localStorage.setItem("txtValue", email);
}
my admin site
</div>
ID:<span id="data"> Email</span><br> 
</div>

document.getElementById("data").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("txtValue");
